# Dynamic Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, dependencies

We have a situation where some of our dependencies have conflicting dependencies.
We depend on A & B.
A dependes on version a of X.
B depends on version b of X.

Are there any dependency management tools that handle this type of a situation. I feel as if I had heard about some dependency management tool that dynamically loaded the dependencies or something. It seemed like it avoided ever running into a situation like above. I think you could specify somehow which version of X to load at a given instant or something.

Is it possible to do something like that? Is there any way in the code you can load and unload the dependency on a need basis?

I have forgotten most of compiler theory. And I haven't dealt much with dependency management. So excuse any ignorance showing through. It's probably genuine!

Comment: I'am not sure to understand your problem but maybe you could check dependy exclusion with maven http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use OSGi or some other framework that manages multiple class-loaders so that the conflicting versions don't end up in the same class loader.
2. You can try to do the same thing yourself on a small scale by creating class loaders.
3. You can use the maven-shade-plugin to rename the packages in one or more copies to avoid the conflict.